# Write / Read Byte array from/to file java

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a java serializable object and I want to write/read that object to/from a file.
Yet Google app engine does not support fileoutputstream and objectoutputstream so I convert the serializable object to a byte array and write it to file

```
$FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(
writableFile, lockForWrite);
$writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytearray));
$writeChannel.closeFinally();
```

Then I read the file:

```
AppEngineFile readableFile = new AppEngineFile(filename);
FileReadChannel readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(readableFile, lockForRead);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(readChannel, "UTF-8"));
String line = reader.toString();
```

I see the log and I got error with UTF-8
Can anybody show me what I did incorrectly ?

Error log:

```
cloud.spam.filter.server.SerializationObject file_io: An error message: invalid stream header: 5B4240312012/07/06 08:00:10
```

Thank  you

Comment: Please provide the error log.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using protobuf for this purpose. Beside the fact that it's more compact format than standard java serialization, it will also give you ability to change (by adding new fields) class to be written into file.